# Using azcopy to copy .bak files to Azure storage

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azcopy

Im trying to copy the contents of my sql server backup .bak files to azure storage using azcopy.
Im using this command in a batch .bat file -

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\AzCopy.exe" ^
/Source:"I:\" /Dest:https://hmlrservicesstorage.****************************/ ^
/DestKey:********************************************** /Pattern:"*.bak" /s /XO
```

On the I drive there are two folders, one a normal folder and the other a network share.
When I run the .bat file through a cmd prompt it runs fine copying all .bak files to the storage, yet when I run the same .bat file through a SQL Server Agent job, using exactly the same .bat file it only copies the network share folder across and not the normal folders contents.

I am copying from an Azure VM in the cloud to azure storage account.
SQL Server is installed on the VM in the Azure cloud.

I cant understand why and would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Where is installed your SQL Server? On your computer on on the network server? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: SQL Server Agent is configured to run under a particular account and may be using a different account than SQL Server itself. Whichever account it is requires file system ACLs granting it appropriate access in your I: drive folders. You can check which account is being used via the Services control panel or via SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Its was to do with permissions in the end.
The SQL Server Agent account needed permissions on the folder.